# Does Java have the concept of "method-scoped static" variables?

Tags: java, scope, static

In C++, there is the concept of a [function-scoped static variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/storage-classes-cpp?view=vs-2019#static), which allows you to limit the scope of a static variable to the function it's used in (e.g. to prevent a function-local constant from being re-initialised on every call).

Does Java possess an equivalent, for example a way to prevent

```java
// ... surrounding class code ...
public void doThingToStuff() {
    final Set<String> stuff = Sets.newHashSet("some", "stuff");
    doThing(stuff);
}
// ... surrounding class code ...
```

from re-initialising the set every time `doThingToStuff` is called?

Comment: local variables only exist during the time of the execution of the method

Comment: Does `stuff` need to be local to the method? Can you move it outside to the surrounding class?

Comment: You can't even put (non *compile-time constant) statics in local classes. Yet.

Comment: @NathanHughes While potentially abusable (especially with non-constants), it's very useful for maintaining a coherent scope for your function-level constants.

Comment: @AK47 I can, but I'd prefer not to scope-creep if possible. If not, as you say, `private static final /*please don't modify the contents of this*/ Set<String>` is an option.

Comment: you can write a static method that sets up some state and then uses it in a lambda that the method returns. then you can call the lambda repeatedly with that state closed over. so the state is local. would that do the same thing?

Comment: Probably, but that does sound like it'll look kind of unreadable compared to the above code.